# Arduino Mhz 433 send a long

Tags: arduino, char, long-integer, radio-transmission

I am working on a project where I am sending data via the Arduino Mhz 433 transmitter and receiver. The data code is coming from a FSR. How ever the code for the data I am receiving is in a Long and the code for the MHZ 433 is in a char.

This is my code for the transmitter plus the FSR

`

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>
RH_ASK driver;


int fsrPin = 0;               // the FSR and 10k resistor are connected to A0
int fsrReading;               // analog reading from the FSR resistor divider
int fsrVoltage;               // analog reading converted to voltage
unsigned long fsrResistance;  // voltage converted to resistance
unsigned long fsrConductance;
long fsrForce = 0;  // resistance converted to force


void setup(void) {
#ifdef RH_HAVE_SERIAL
  Serial.begin(9600);
#endif
  if (!driver.init())
#ifdef RH_HAVE_SERIAL
    Serial.println("init failed");
#else
    ;
#endif
}


void loop(void) {


  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrPin);
  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.println(fsrReading);


  // analog voltage reading ranges from about 0 to 1023 which maps to 0V to 5V (= 5000mV)
  fsrVoltage = map(fsrReading, 0, 1023, 0, 5000);
  Serial.print("Voltage reading in mV = ");
  Serial.println(fsrVoltage);


  if (fsrVoltage == 0) {
    Serial.println("No pressure");
  } else {
    // The voltage = Vcc * R / (R + FSR) where R = 10K and Vcc = 5V
    // so FSR = ((Vcc - V) * R) / V
    fsrResistance = 5000 - fsrVoltage;  // fsrVoltage is in millivolts so 5V = 5000mV
    fsrResistance *= 10000;             // 10k resistor
    fsrResistance /= fsrVoltage;
    Serial.print("FSR resistance in ohms = ");
    Serial.println(fsrResistance);


    fsrConductance = 1000000;  // we measure in micromhos so
    fsrConductance /= fsrResistance;
    Serial.print("Conductance in microMhos: ");
    Serial.println(fsrConductance);


    // Use the two FSR guide graphs to approximate the force
    if (fsrConductance <= 1000) {
      fsrForce = fsrConductance / 80;
      Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
      Serial.println(fsrForce);
    } else {
      fsrForce = fsrConductance - 1000;
      fsrForce /= 30;
      Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
      Serial.println(fsrForce);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("--------------------");
  delay(1000);


  const char *msg = "Hello World!";
  driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
  driver.waitPacketSent();
  delay(1000);
}
```

This is the reciever code:

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>
RH_ASK driver;
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
 if (!driver.init())
 Serial.println("init failed");
}
void loop()
{
 uint8_t buf[12];
 uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
 if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
 {
 int i;
 // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
 Serial.print("Message: ");
 Serial.println((char*)buf);
 }
}
```

Running this code I do get "hello world" but have been having issues gettiing the data from the FSR to send over the Mhz433

Comment: "but have been having issues"... what issues?

Answer (score 0):

try convert your long var to char array :

```
char* msg = String(fsrResistance).c_str();
```